# How can I manage Dell H700 RAID controllers from the Linux command line?

Tags: raid, dell, dell-perc, h700

Previous PERC controllers could all be managed/monitored by the LSI MegaCLI tools.  The latest release of those tools does not appear to recognize my H700 card:

```
$ sudo /opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 -adpCount 

Controller Count: 0.
```

Are there any options aside from installing the massive OMSA suite?

-Ben

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You didn't mention which "latest release" you used.  I just tried this and it seems to work fine now.  The Dell H700 is using this chipset:

```
# lspci -v | grep LSI
01:00.0 RAID bus controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic LSI MegaSAS 9260 (rev 05)
```

Visit the support section of LSI's site, the 9260 is part of the "MegaRAID Value Line".  That took me to [MegaRAID SAS 9260-8i](http://www.lsi.com/storage_home/products_home/internal_raid/megaraid_sas/6gb_s_value_line/sas9260-8i/index.html), click on the "Downloads" tab from there.  I downloaded "MegaCLI - Linux (MegaRAID Release 5.0)", version 8.01.06 from 28-FEB-11.  Unzip the package, then install/run it like this:

```
# rpm -i Lib_Utils-1.00-08.noarch.rpm MegaCli-8.01.06-1.i386.rpm 
# /opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 -AdpAllInfo -aALL  

Adapter #0

==============================================================================
                    Versions
                ================
Product Name    : PERC H700 Integrated
Serial No       : 0000000
FW Package Build: 12.10.0-0025
```

I blanked the serial number here for privacy reasons.  You might need to do a firmware upgrade to your card as well to make it compatible.  I wouldn't be surprised that this didn't work when you tried it and has only been fixed since.  I try to hold off buying these new controllers from Dell until as long as possible after they've been released because of issues like that.

Comment: The latest release `MegaCLI 8.07.14` opens `/proc/devices` to first scan for adapters. In VMWare ESX, this path does not exist. Try `8.07.07` instead.

Comment: This is an old question, and much seems to have changed. I can only seem to find downloads with .rpm packages not .deb packages. Any more up to date tips appreciated.

Comment: OK, some progress. Can convert to .deb with the alien package. Tried `8.07.07` and silently ignores the PERC H700 as well.

Comment: Alas the earliest megacli I can find is 5.3 here: https://www.broadcom.com/site-search?filters[pages][content_type][type]=and&filters[pages][content_type][values][]=Downloads&page=1&per_page=100&q=%20MegaRAID%20SAS%202108%20MegaCLI and it doesn't see the controller either.  I can't seem to find 6.0 *8.01.06) alas.

Comment: So I found `MegaCli-8.01.06-1.i386.rpm` here: http://repo.semantico.net/redhat/6Server/os/x86_64/, but alas as I'm on a .deb based system I need to convert it using the `alien` package converter. But it won't convert as it's for i386 architecture and I'm on x86_64.

Comment: OK, I converted it in a 32bit OS VM, and installed it fine on my server with i386 arch enabled. But alas even though it is 5.0  version 8.01.06  I don't see what Greg Smith sees, I see what Insyte sees. MegaCLI does not see my PERC H700. :-(

Comment: And I finally succeeded in getting a version that works. Following these instructions: https://www.mybluelinux.com/debian-linux-and-lsi-megaraid-sas/ and using "xenial main" as the repo even though I'm focal not xenial, That installs megaCLI v8.07.14 and it works, the one trick, that I may have overlooked is that megacli must run as root to see the RAID controller. That is `megacli -adpCount ` sees 0 adapters  but `sudo megacli -adpCount` sees 1 and I can interact with it too. All is good now.

Answer (score -4):

Have you taken a look at mdadm? See here for more information:
[mdadm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mdadm)

Comment: That is specific to software raid.